# ValueError while reshaping array to 4dim Keras API format

Tags: python, numpy, keras, scikit-learn, deep-learning

DL beginner here. I'm trying to implement LeNet using Keras and apply it on good ol' MNIST.

```
class LeNet:
@staticmethod
def build(height, width, depth, classes):
    model= Sequential()
    inputshape= (height,width, depth)

    if K.image_data_format()== 'channels_first':
        inputshape= (depth, height, width)

    #build model
    model.add(Conv2d(20, (5,5), padding= "same", input_shape= inputshape))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size= (2,2), strides=(2,2)))

    #replicate what's above again
    model.add(Conv2d(50, (5,5), padding= "same"))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size= (2,2), strides=(2,2)))

    #Fully Connected Layers
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(500))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))

    #softmax
    model.add(Dense(classes))
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))


    return model
```

Then I load the dataset

```
print('[INFO] Accessing MNIST...')

dataset= loadmat('mnist-original.mat')
data=dataset['data']
```

Now I'm trying to reshape the data whose current shape is (784, 70000) by

```
data= data.reshape(data.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)
```

But I get an error that says **ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 54880000 into shape (784,28,28,1)**

Where am I going wrong here? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: How would you fit a 784x70000 matrix in 784x28x28 positions? You have a factor of ~89 too little positions.

Comment: How do I rectify this? I find online tutorials to be doing the very same thing and it works for them.

Comment: Your data shape should be 70000x784.

Comment: When loading with `loadmat` (from a MATLAB source), the array might be the transpose of what you expect.  Make sure you understand what the dimensions mean, especially if you are working with several tutorials and data sources.  What does the 70000 represent?  The 784 (which = 28*28).